# How to program a GIF using any type of image/ object with processing?

Tags: java, processing

I have used Java language for beginners is used with object type calling so there's an app or software called processing that I used that's a bit easy at making programs... (https://processing.org/)

What could be the best shortest example to make a animated GIF using shapes/ images?

What way could be the best way to make a GIF animated in regular Java without using processing software?

What could be the easiest examples for a beginner to do an animated GIF?

Comment: Feel free to post comments and post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. But I'll try to help in a general sense:

You need to [break your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and then take those steps on one at a time. Can you create a simple animation? Something simple like a circle moving around the screen. Separately from that, can you export a single `.png` image from a sketch? Again, just something simple. Work your way forward in small steps: can you then export each frame of a simple animation as a `.png` file?

Then when you have those `.png` files, you can use something like Image Magick to convert them into an animated gif file.

[The Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/) is your best friend for questions like this. The `save()` and `saveFrame()` functions could come in handy for exporting an animation as a gif.

Please try something, and if you get stuck, post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a more specific technical question in a new post. Good luck.